# Does the CSS3 ::selection pseudo-element apply to all child elements as well?

Tags: css, css-selectors, selection

I'm using this code:

```css
::-moz-selection { background: #c92127; color: #fff; text-shadow: none; }
::selection { background: #c92127; color: #fff; text-shadow: none; }
```

Now I want to use this on any element inside a certain div.

My code for my wrapper is

```
<div id="wrapper" class="Red">
```

So I went with this for my CSS selector

```css
div#wrapper.Red::-moz-selection { background: #c92127; color: #fff; text-shadow: none; }
div#wrapper.Red::selection { background: #c92127; color: #fff; text-shadow: none; }
```

But this does not work. It does work when I just use the selection code at the top of this question though.

So my question is: Does `::selection` apply to all child elements (i.e. my selector is wrong) or is this not possible?

Here is an example in response to BoltClock's jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/6DBhV/1/

Comment: Did you make sure to add the `::-moz-selection` version in case you're testing this in Firefox? Are you using the same styles as in the first block of code?

Comment: I did yes, i will edit the question to make it clearer

Comment: Your selector should work (the text and background color anyway, not the text shadow): http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/6DBhV Even if you have a set of base `::selection` styles as in your first block of code, the more specific one should still work. Can you put up a test case or show us more code?

Comment: Added a fiddle to show you what i mean :) Cheers

Comment: That was the part you didn't show. Knew it. I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `div#wrapper.Red::selection` styles will indeed *not* be inherited by the `::selection` of any children (in your fiddle, it's `div#test::selection`). Due to the way inheritance works in CSS, pseudo-elements cannot inherit from other pseudo-elements even if their real elements are related in some way as parents or children. The issue of nested selections was covered in much greater depth in [this CSS WG mailing list thread](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2008Oct/0268.html).<sup>1</sup>

The reason why your `::selection` style works is because the pseudo-element is applied to all elements, including both of your `<div>`s.

An easy solution to this is to separate `::selection` from the rest of your simple selectors with a combinator:

```css
/* Notice the space here - the descendant combinator */
div#wrapper.Red ::-moz-selection { background: #c92127; color: #fff; text-shadow: none; }
div#wrapper.Red ::selection { background: #c92127; color: #fff; text-shadow: none; }
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/6DBhV/2)

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>This is also one of the reasons why `::selection` was [dropped from CSS UI 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#changes-list). Here's hoping it'll return in UI 4 after it's further tested and defined.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

To apply/include all child elements, this is my solution :

```
div#wrapper > * ::selection, 
div#wrapper > * ::-moz-selection {
    background-color: #c92127;
}
```

It works for Firefox and Chrome.

Ref: [CSS * Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_all.asp) and 
[CSS element>element Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_gt.asp)